# Angular 6 project architecture

Tags: angular

I am  new at angular 6, I am trying to make a multi module application.
I would like to build each module separately and deploy it so it can be tested
Then this module can be integrated together into main application .

Say there is module A which can deployed on its own and developed by team A
Then module B developed by team B and it can also be deployed
At last all modules string together and finally the main application can be deployed and tested

I was looking into building angular libraries, but don't know whether it will work

Basically I would like to follow what angular team has done, different packages which could be imported and used

Comment: You should to separate your app in modules, check this real world app: https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app/tree/master/src/app/editor

Comment: try to use this package. github.com/ngx-rocket/generator-ngx-rocket but first, read the documentation of this package and purpose of usage. may be it will be helpfull for fulfilling your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was looking something more. I would like to build  angular libraries or node modules which I can import in the main application. 
By doing this I would like individual team to build test and deploy each module.
At the end all of this node modules or libraries be used in  the main application

Comment: You can already do this with angular CLI via packaging it as a library. It's in the documentation. You will of course have to find somewhere to host the packages if you don't want public to download it.

Comment: I found that and thanks for the info, I have a doubt rather can I extend the library concept to  have a library which have have only services which  in turn make REST calls.

Answer (score 1):

Study angular's lazy loading concept. by using lazy loading you can break a project in multiple modules and its make your project fast too. the best place to know about this is angular's official documentation. the link is given below-
https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

After that go for this following link-
https://angular.io/cli/generate#library-command